# Get audio file to use custom html 5 video controls

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have an html5 video on a page and an audio file I would like to use as background music.  Is it possible to have the audio controls tied into the video controls (mute, volume, play, pause, etc..).  The audio cannot be part of the video file because the video pauses and I'd still like the background music to play and loop.

```
<video id="video" data-setup="{}" >
  <source src="video/MyVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="video/MyVideo.webmhd.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
  <source src="video/MyVideo.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
  <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5. Maybe you should upgrade.</p>
</video>

<audio id="music" loop="loop">
    <source src="audio/background.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="audio/background.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/background.wav" type="audio/wav" />
    <p> Your browser doesn't support HTML5.  Maybe you should upgrade.</p>
</audio>

        <input type="button" value="PLAY" id="playpause" onclick="playOrPause()" class="button_play">
        <input type="button" value="Mute" id="mutebutton" onclick="muteOrUnmute()" class="button_play">
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.getElementById('video').volume+=0.2" class="button">
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="document.getElementById('video').volume-=0.2" class="button">
```

and some JavaScript

```
    function playOrPause() {
        if (video.ended || video.paused) {
            video.play();
            document.getElementById("playpause").value="PAUSE";
        } else {
            video.pause();
            document.getElementById("playpause").value="PLAY";
                }   
        }

    var m = document.getElementById('mutebutton')[0];
    video.onvolumechange = function(e) {
    mutebutton.value = video.muted ? 'Unmute' : 'Mute';
        }


    function muteOrUnmute() {
        if (video.muted) {
            video.muted = false;
            document.getElementById("mutebutton").value="Mute";
        } else {
            video.muted = true
            document.getElementById("mutebutton").value="Unmute";
                }   
                return false;
        }
```

I'm new to JavaScript and html5 so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "The audio cannot be part of the video file because the video pauses and I'd still like the background music to play and loop."  This sounds like you want two different sets of controls: one to pause the video and allow the audio to keep playing.

Comment: @dfmiller I want one set of controls.  The audio will continue to play after the video pauses because the audio is looped while the audio in the video (and the video) will pause at specific points that I have written Javascript for.  Ideally I just want the audio to start playing when the play button is pressed for the video and then only be controlled by the mute/unmute and volume controls for the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I made a variable for my music

```
var a =document.getElementById("music");
```

and to connect the play functions together I added. `a.play()` to my play button and for the mute/unmute buttons I did this

```
function muteOrUnmute() {
        if (video.muted) {
            video.muted = false;
            a.muted = false;
            document.getElementById("mutebutton").value="Mute";
        } else {
            video.muted = true;
            a.muted = true;
            document.getElementById("mutebutton").value="Unmute";
                }   
                return false;
        }
```

For the volume up and down controls I did this:

```
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.getElementById('video').volume+=0.2; document.getElementById('music').volume+=0.1" class="button">
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="document.getElementById('video').volume-=0.2; document.getElementById('music').volume-=0.1" class="button">
```